# How does FFMPEG command works in the following code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ffmpeg, deep-learning, pytorch

**How does FFMPEG working here?**

```
import sys, os, pdb
import numpy as np
import subprocess
from tqdm import tqdm
       

def extract(vid_dir, frame_dir, start, end, redo=False):
  class_list = sorted(os.listdir(vid_dir))[start:end]

  print("Classes =", class_list)
  
  for ic,cls in enumerate(class_list): 
    vlist = sorted(os.listdir(vid_dir + cls))
    print("")
    print(ic+1, len(class_list), cls, len(vlist))
    print("")
    for v in tqdm(vlist):
      outdir = os.path.join(frame_dir, cls, v[:-4])
      
      # Checking if frames already extracted
      if os.path.isfile( os.path.join(outdir, 'done') ) and not redo: continue
      try:  
        os.system('mkdir -p "%s"'%(outdir))
        # check if horizontal or vertical scaling factor
        o = subprocess.check_output('ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=width,height -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 "%s"'%(os.path.join(vid_dir, cls, v)), shell=True).decode('utf-8')
        lines = o.splitlines()
        width = int(lines[0].split('=')[1])
        height = int(lines[1].split('=')[1])
        resize_str = '-1:256' if width>height else '256:-1'

        # extract frames
        os.system('ffmpeg -i "%s" -r 25 -q:v 2 -vf "scale=%s" "%s"  > /dev/null 2>&1'%( os.path.join(vid_dir, cls, v), resize_str, os.path.join(outdir, '%05d.jpg')))
        nframes = len([ fname for fname in os.listdir(outdir) if fname.endswith('.jpg') and len(fname)==9])
        if nframes==0: raise Exception 

        os.system('touch "%s"'%(os.path.join(outdir, 'done') ))
      except:
        print("ERROR", cls, v)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  vid_dir   = sys.argv[1]
  frame_dir = sys.argv[2]
  start     = int(sys.argv[3])
  end       = int(sys.argv[4])
  extract(vid_dir, frame_dir, start, end, redo=True)

os.system('ffmpeg -i "%s" -r 25 -q:v 2 -vf "scale=%s" "%s"  > /dev/null 2>&1'%( os.path.join(vid_dir, cls, v), resize_str, os.path.join(outdir, '%05d.jpg')))
```

-i --> Input_file (320x240)

-r --> frame rate (it will extract 25 frame of every video)

-q --> what does this mean?

"scale=%s --> Unable to understand this? how does this work for -1:256 ratio [will it resize the video to 256x256 dimension]?

Can anyone explain me this?

Comment: Badly. This code is vulnerable to shell injection faults. `os.system()` should never be used; `subprocess.Popen()` should be used instead, with the default `shell=False`. If you _must_ use `os.system` or otherwise generate code to be parsed by a shell for some reason, use `shlex.quote()` in Python 3 or `pipes.quote()` in Python 2 to escape variables before insertion.

Comment: That said, are you _only_ asking what `scale=` means on the ffmpeg command line? That's arguably more a question for [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [unix.se]. And when asking there, it would be useful to show your work ("I checked the man page and it says X, but this doesn't make sense because Y") to better contextualize what's unclear and why it's unclear.

Comment: To explain what I meant about security faults, think about what happens if you have a video named `Why you should never run $(rm -rf ~).mkv` as your input file. Or, if you change your quoting type to be single quotes, maybe a video named `Why $(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)' is dangerous in all quoting types.mkv`

Comment: This isn't really a Python question. It's about `ffmpeg` command line options. Docs are at https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis

Comment: if we keeps scale=-1:256 , it will scale down the image to 256x256? isn't it? @Char

Comment: Yes, ffmpeg not comes in python it is just command line. Therefore, I were unable to understand it.

Comment: If you still have the same question after taking the Python out and only asking about the command line for ffmpeg, then why include Python in your question at all? Find a place where questions about command-line tool usage is on-topic, and ask there.

Comment: Okay Okay, I got you <3